# SQL Timeline Query

Tags: sql

read already some post but was not able to find a solution yet.

I gota table which looks like this:

[image: Initial data]

and I would like to transform this data, so that I got a line (or row) per ID and an entry per date which displays the Status. The value column does not change its value for the corresponding id.

[image]

or

[image]

I am currently not able to do it. Even without the value row/line.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  date1 text,
  status1 INT,
  value1 INT
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '01.01.2022', 1, 60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '01.01.2022', 1, 30);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '01.01.2022', 7, 90);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '02.01.2022', 7, 60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '02.01.2022', 7, 30);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '02.01.2022', 3, 90);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '03.01.2022', 7, 60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '03.01.2022', 5, 30);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '03.01.2022', 7, 90);
```

Based on your suggestions I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT id, value1
    FROM test
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT(AVG(status1) FOR date1 IN(select DISTINCT date1
                           from test)) AS PivotTable;
```

But I can not find my error.

Comment: Post your query what you have tried. Also add which RDBMS it is

Comment: you can try pivoting like this https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/

Comment: As RDBMS I use MS Access as a front end but could also directly connect to the MS SQL DB

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  date text,
  status INT,
  value INT
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '01.01.2022', 1, 60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '01.01.2022', 1, 30);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '01.01.2022', 7, 90);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '02.01.2022', 7, 60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '02.01.2022', 7, 30);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '02.01.2022', 3, 90);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '03.01.2022', 7, 60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '03.01.2022', 5, 30);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '03.01.2022', 7, 90);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
ID,
MAX(VALUE) AS VALUE, 
sum(CASE WHEN date = '01.01.2022' THEN status ELSE 0 END) AS '01.01.2022',
sum(CASE WHEN date = '02.01.2022' THEN status ELSE 0 END) AS '02.01.2022',
sum(CASE WHEN date = '03.01.2022' THEN status ELSE 0 END) AS '03.01.2022'
FROM test
GROUP BY ID;
```

| ID | VALUE | 01.01.2022 | 02.01.2022 | 03.01.2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 1 | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | 30 | 1 | 7 | 5 |
| 3 | 90 | 7 | 3 | 7 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2dD4HebHdcmLazEVWsCvv3/0)

Comment: Thx YuTing, is this also possible generic, since I got way more dates than just the three days. Like a distinct on the date column or something like that?

Comment: What if they have 100s of rows ?